# how to import csv file in nodejs and write it in mysql using sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm, sequelize.js

i wanted to import csv file from UI ,read it and store it into mysql db using some validation and ORM like sequelize, how to do it?
sample.csv

```
code,name,phone
"A1","Jonh W","3342423"
"A2","King K","6234234"



module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
  user_id: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      autoIncrement: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    code: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
   name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    phone: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    }
    }, {
      tableName: 'users',
      timestamps: false,
      underscored: true
    });

     };
  return User;
}
```

this is the csv file want to import and given User entity for the database to store

Comment: i would set the autoIncrement for user_id to true. then i would use [fs to read lines from the csv](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-csv-files-with-node-js/) and then use the User.Create function to pass the code, name and phone. The Id will then automatically be set by sequelize

Comment: how to read from UI submit ?

Comment: You need a graphical user interface for the file input? what do you use for the frontend?

Comment: for frontend i am using ,vue js

Comment: if you use [vue to let the user select a file](https://serversideup.net/uploading-files-vuejs-axios/) , you can use axios to send the file to your nodejs backend, where you can either store it as a file on your server and then read it with fs or handle it directly.